# How to add a file path in -SetPropertyValue while adding a DSN through Add-OdbcDsn (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, google-bigquery, odbc, simba

I have added DSN for ODBC driver by using below pwoershell script

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "My_Connew" -DriverName "Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery" -DsnType "System" -Platform "64-bit" -SetPropertyValue @("Email=246384378418-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com", "Key File Path=C:\vocus-sandpit-dfa36ce40776.json")
```

Everything wroking well but it can't able to add the file path.

[image]

Wondering how i can add file path through -SetPropertyValue ?

Comment: Try with `"KeyFilePath=..."` instead of `"Key File Path=...`

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasR.Jessen, it's working well now, successfully able to add a file path, now trying to add Catalog (Project) and Dataset seems like the below script is doing nothing. Any tips?  -SetPropertyValue @("Email=246384378418-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com", "KeyFilePath=C:\vocus-sandpit-dfa36ce40776.json","Catalog(Project)=vocus-sandpitvocus-sandpit","Dataset=vocus_rawnew")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels used by the UI might not correspond 1-to-1 with the actual key names in the configuration schema - for example, the real key name for `Key File Path` is just `KeyFilePath`

To figure out what to use, simply consult [the documentation](https://simba.wpengine.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/options/options-general.htm) and find the appropriate key name for a given configuration option in the UI, then use those, e.g.:

```
Set-OdbcDsn -Name "My_Connew" -SetPropertyValue @(
    "Email=246384378418-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com", 
    "KeyFilePath=C:\vocus-sandpit-dfa36ce40776.json",
    "Catalog=vocus-sandpitvocus-sandpit",
    "DefaultDataset=vocus_rawnew"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasR.Jessen, everything is working well now. thanks for the help.