# DSN setup Simba ODBC Driver for Big Query using powershell

Tags: powershell, google-bigquery, odbc, dsn

Im trying to setup dsn using powershell but I cannot get 'Encrypted Sensitive Data' parameter configured. It always keep 'For currently user only' and I need 'For all users'. this paramater is new in the latest odbc driver version, before didn't exist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl9ZE.png)

Im using the following code structure (I substitute my personal values for xx just to show the code):

Add-OdbcDsn -Name "xx" -DriverName "Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery" -DsnType "System" -Platform "64-bit" -SetPropertyValue @("EncryptedSensitiveData=0","OAuthMechanism=0", "Email=xx", "KeyFilePath=xx", "Catalog=xx", "DefaultDataset=xx")

Comment: Are you running the setup As Admin?  Type the name of the tool in the windows start and then right click tool and open as admin.

Comment: I’m already running as admin

Comment: Did you see followin g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74545704/how-to-add-a-file-path-in-setpropertyvalue-while-adding-a-dsn-through-add-odbcd?force_isolation=true

Comment: Yes but it was not helpful. I already check simba odbc driver documentation and didn’t find how this parameter can be identified.

Comment: Here are instructions and location where you can ask additional questions : https://insightsoftware.com/blog/how-to-install-simba-google-bigquery-odbc-connector/

Comment: It works but my objectiv is to do using powershell

Comment: Using ODBC is a feature of Powershell.  Powershell is like any application and requires a driver to access the database.  ODBC the driver must be installed and configured properly.  Other types of databases (like oledb) the driver is hidden in the libraries, but still exists.